# Test recursive method with OCMock

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have method:

```
+(void)deleteImage:(KRImage*)image usingFileManager:(NSFileManager*)fileManager
{
    if(!fileManager)
        [[self class] deleteImage:image usingFileManager:[NSFileManager defaultManager]];
    else
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:image.filepath error:NULL];
}
```

I would like to test that defaultManager will be used if i used nil as a parameter. I tried do it using code:

```
-(void)testThatDefaultManagerWillBeUsedWhenNilIsPassed
{
    image = [KRImage imageWithURLString:@"imageToDelete" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [[[partiallyMockImage expect] classMethod] deleteImage:OCMOCK_ANY usingFileManager:[NSFileManager defaultManager]];
    [[partiallyMockImage class] deleteImage:image usingFileManager:nil];
    [partiallyMockImage verify];
}
```

Class KRImage is a entitle class with filepath field. It is a subclass of NSManagedObject. Used method `[KRImage imageWithURLString:(NSString*)urlString inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context` works fine and returns one of mine objects (I checked it).

Unfortunatelly I see only error: "expected method was not invoked". I really don't know why it doesn't work. I use OCMock framework for tests.

Comment: This should work. Can you show us how `partialluMockImage` is created?

Comment: I don't know if it is the reason of your problem, but in the if branch you should send the message to self, not [self class]. Self if already the Class object.